# Opencv bounding box overlap

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Hello i have a problem in opencv when i change bounding box color difference is working
but when i change bounding box color same or in blue channel color the bounding box is same color in win1 and win2 please help me

if i you understand i'm sorry

[in the picture 1 is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atls8.png)

[in the picture 2 has a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngcl3.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

obj_one = [np.array([103,94,52]),
           np.array([180,255,255])]

obj_two = [np.array([49,94,52]),
           np.array([123,255,255])]

def track_object(img_src,HSV_Lower,HSV_Upper,Color):
    org_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(src=img_src,code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    color_mask = cv2.inRange(src=org_hsv,lowerb=HSV_Lower,upperb=HSV_Upper)

    detection = []
    is_object = False

    (conts,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(image=color_mask, 
                        mode=cv2.RETR_TREE,method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for obj_cnts in conts:
       (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(obj_cnts)
       if cv2.contourArea(obj_cnts) > 500:
          img_src = cv2.rectangle(img=img_src,pt1=(x,y),pt2= 
          (x+w,y+h),color=Color,thickness=2)

    return img_src,is_object

while True:
  try:
    ret,frame = cap.read()    
    win1 = track_object(frame,obj_one[0],obj_one[1],(255,0,0))
    win2 = track_object(frame,obj_two[0],obj_two[1],(0,255,0))

    cv2.imshow('Org', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
  except:
    pass
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```